# mapbox - disabling viewing of unrendered white tiles outside of the map

Tags: javascript, web-mapping, cartography, mapbox

I'm looking to disable being able to move the map in such a way that one can move outside of the map area:
[image]

I don't want to be able to see the surrounding white areas when the map is dragged. I have turned off wrapping as I don't want any horizontal duplication.

#### Code:

```js
    // Create a map in the div #map
    L.mapbox.map('map', 'example', {
        minZoom: 2,//need to change it to 1 maybe 0 for mobile devices
        // These options apply to the tile layer in the map.
        tileLayer: {
            // This map option disables world wrapping. by default, it is false.
            continuousWorld: false,
            // This option disables loading tiles outside of the world bounds.
            noWrap: true
        }
    });
```

---

I have a suspicion I might be able to utilise [`maxBounds`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/maxbounds/) or [`fitBounds`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/fitbounds/) but I'm no quite sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean to [disable panning](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/disable-zooming-panning/), here's how:

First declare your map variable:

```
// Create a map in the div #map
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'example', {
    minZoom: 2,//need to change it to 1 maybe 0 for mobile devices
    // These options apply to the tile layer in the map.
    tileLayer: {
        // This map option disables world wrapping. by default, it is false.
        continuousWorld: false,
        // This option disables loading tiles outside of the world bounds.
        noWrap: true
    }
});
```

Then disable drag:

```
map.dragging.disable();
```

You could also enable dragging at higher zoom levels, but disable it when zoomed all the way out:

```
map.on('zoomend', function() {
    if (map.getZoom() < 4) {
        map.dragging.disable();
    else {
        map.dragging.enable();
    }
}
```